# How to bind click function on select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it is possible to set an selected option dynamically for HTML Select element like

```
$('#choose option:eq(2)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

but in an specific case I need to explicitly click on option of the select and make it selected. Is this achievable, and what I am doing wrong on getting it?

```js
$("#clickme").on("click",function(){
  var se=$("#choose");
  se.show();
  se[0].size=5;
  //$('#choose option:eq(2)').attr("selected", "selected").change(); 
    $('#choose option:eq(2)').click();
});

 $('body').on('change','#choose', function() {
    $('body').css('background', this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme">Click Me To Open Select Box</button>
<select id="choose" name="choose" style=display:none;"">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="gold">gold</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cant you just give that specific option some id attribute and do something like: `var evt = new MouseEvent('click'); elem.dispatchEvent(evt);` elem being the element you gave the id?

Comment: try `$('#choose option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: for select element it is better to use change event. is there a special reason why you need to use click?

Answer (score 0):

First you need add prop selected on right choose.

```
$('#choose option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true).click();
```

Second you need extend events (click) to .ON which change background color.

```
$('body').on('change, click','#choose', function() {
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/daremachine/k2s8obz3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like so:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
$(function(){
var choose = $('#choose'), bod = $('body');
choose.change(function(){
  bod.css('background', $(this).val());
});
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  choose.val('blue'); choose.show().change();
});
}); // end jQuery ready
```

```css
/* external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  position:relative; background:#ccc;
}
#test{
  padding:10px;
}
#clickme{
  padding:3px 5px; border:1px solid #aaa; border-radius:3px; margin-bottom:5px;
}
#choose{
  display:none; clear:left;
}
#clickme,#choose{
  float:left; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='test'>
    <input id='clickme' type='button' value='Click Me To Open Select Box' />
    <select id='choose' size='3'>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='gold'>Gold</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have faced problem to that after alert message in the drop down, not able to re-populate previous value. Below is the solution, as we are dealing with Jquery then code should be in jquery only
function testfn()
{
    $('#test').multiselect({
        multiple : false,
        header : false,
        selectedList : 3,
        minWidth : 100,
        // noneSelectedText:"--Select--",
        height : 100
    });
}
```